# PHP Waiting for WSDL (Salesforce) process to finish

Tags: php, concurrency, wsdl, salesforce

I am using Php with Salesforce WSDL API.

What I have going is a PHP page doing several things.

1. Create inform via WSDL to Salesforce and have it return an Id.
2. Using that created Id to assign to a variable so that it can update a record via WSDL into Salesforce

   function createRecord($Object, $FieldData){
    //does it magic by connecting to Salesforce, 
    return $Id;
   }

   $newRecord = createRecord();

   $record->contact__c = $newRecord;
   $sfConn->update(array($record), 'Campaign');

So what happens is that $newRecord is suppose to get a assign with value from function createRecord, what sometime happens is that createRecord doesn't process fast enough and so $newRecord get assign with NULL.

Anything I can do to make sure createRecord finish executing before "$record->contact__c" is called?

---

Within the createRecord($Object, $FieldData) is this code

```
$sfConn2 = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$sfClient = $sfConn2->createConnection(WSDL_FILE);
$sfLogin = $sfConn2->login(SF_UN, SF_PW);

        $newRec = new stdclass();           
        foreach ($FieldData as $key => $value){
            $newRec->$key = $value;
        }

            $createResponse = $sfConn2->create(array($newRec), $Object);

            if($createResponse->success == 1){
               return $createResponse->id;  
            }else{
               return FALSE;
            }
```

So the most likely culprit would be that there is an exception such as drop connection within the createRecord?

If that is so, should I handle that within the createRecord function or outside of it during the assignment of createRecord to the $newRecord Variable?

Comment: If your `createRecord` function is returning prematurely, it might help to see some of its code.

Comment: posted snippet of the code. Its not just that it return prematurely, it's just that the script just keep running and assign it with whatever is within the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) where ever you can with salesforce api as I have noticed sometimes HTTP errors occur and connections can drop randomly. This way you can test the SOAP calls coming back and ensure they did not fail and have the proper values.

You should use [SalesForce's PHP Toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP) to reduce known issues and not have to invent code all yourself: https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP

If you are trying to insert/create a contact/lead object for example and your using sales force [`create`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm) command inside of your `createRecord()` function it would be much better/safer to use SalesForce [`upsert`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm) command.

If you want more help then this you'll need to show some of your code.